# Python Type Overloads

Tags: python, overloading, python-typing

I've been using the best part of an hour to try to figure out why Pylance is indicating that there's an error with an overload whole I see none.

Here's my code

```py
PR = TypeVar('PR', bound=str)
VA = TypeVar('VA')

class NS(Mapping[PR, VA]):
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, property: PR) -> VA:
        ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, property: Sequence[PR]) -> List[VA]:
        ...
    def __getitem__(self, property: PR|Sequence[PR]) -> VA|List[VA]:
        # function implementation
```

[image: see the line with a red indicator]

[image: Pylance]

Comment: In case I'm doing it wrong, someone should help me figure it out. I want a list of values `VA` returned when a sequence of properties `PR` is supplied. If a single property is supplied, return a single value.

Comment: mmm the last getitem doesn't have the overload decorator? besides that the signature of the first and second are a subset of the third

Comment: @Copperfield the last getitem is the function implementation.

Comment: I tried to remove the annotation on the function's implementation and I got a new error "Type of parameter 'property' is unknown"

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that when multiple values are passed to `__getitem__` i.e `mapping['a','b','c']`, they are supplied as a tuple. Using `Sequence` was too generic. My code now

```
    def __getitem__(self, property: PR) -> VA:
        ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, property: Tuple[PR, ...]) -> List[VA]:
        ...
    def __getitem__(self, property: PR|Tuple[PR, ...]) -> VA|List[VA]:
       # function's implementation
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well it does to pylance

Comment: This is possibly because `str` is also a `Sequence[str]`. We really need something like `NonStrSequence`...